# Difference between openjdk-6-jre, openjdk-6-jre-headless, openjdk-6-jre-lib

Tags: java

I am having trouble understanding some of the basics of Java JRE.

I need to run Java code in an embedded system and for this I need a minimal Java Runtime Environment installed in a Linux kernel, that is to say, the minimum package necessary for executing Java binaries. I think it is not possible to do this only with a JVM (the JRE package is necessary, am I wrong here?)

The thing is, when looking at the Debian repositories I don't quite understand the differences between the packages `openjdk-6-jre`, `openjdk-6-jre-headless` and `openjdk-6-jre-lib`. Will Java programs run only with the former? or, are the three of them needed?

This is an issue as there is a big difference in size (MB) between them.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You are correct in that you will need a JRE package to run any Java application.

Since you say you're running on an embedded platform I assume that the Java application you want to run has no GUI. In that case, you will be fine with `openjdk-6-jre-headless`. This is explained on the [openjdk-6-jre-headless package page here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150911200230/https://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-6-jre-headless) "Minimal Java runtime - needed for executing non GUI Java programs".

As you can see [from the debian package details page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150911200230/https://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-6-jre-headless), `openjdk-6-jre-headless` depends on `openjdk-6-jre-lib` (among other packages), so that will get installed either way.

If however the Java application you want to run has a GUI, you will need `openjdk-6-jre` instead of `openjdk-6-jre-headless`

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I have to compile a linux kernel 2.6... for this platform and I am not sure if it is possible to incorporate in the build process the jre (whatever version, lowest in size if possible). Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: If you mean include a jre with the kernel then as far as I know that's not possible - the jre lives in userspace not the kernel.

Comment: The link reports error: "two or more packages specified (openjdk-6-jre-headless squeeze)".

Comment: what about the differences between `openjdk-11-jdk-headless` and `openjdk-11-jdk` on Linux(ubuntu 18.10), where we can find relative information?

Comment: You can search for ubuntu packages here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/

The relevant ones you're looking for are https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/openjdk-11-jdk-headless and https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/openjdk-11-jdk

Comment: You can also use the `site:` filter from your preferred search engine, if it supports it, to find package details with following search term:
`site:packages.ubuntu.com "package name of interest"` for ubuntu or `site:packages.debian.org "package name of interest"` for debian and similarly for other distributions

Comment: @Woodham The links in your answer seem to be broken. Please check and update them if you can.

Comment: OP wanted differences and you answered what to choose on his situation - it does not answer the question ⁉️

Comment: Consider that when you pick the non headless version, the OS must support it and in systems like linux your non headless installation will bring a bunch of other libraries and tools as well. It is not only those inside the jdk distribution.

Answer (score 16):

The main reason for having two distinct packages available are the dependencies of the packages. `openjdk-6-jre` will also depend on:

```
libasound2, libgif4, libjpeg62, libpng12-0, libpulse0 , libx11-6, libxext6, libxi6, libxrender1, libxtst6 and zlib1g
```

And contrary to the previous comment `openjdk-6-jre` depends on `openjdk-6-jre-headless`, making the latter really just a subset.