# What is the difference between openjdk-7-jre-headless VS openjdk-7-jre?

Tags: java

What is the difference between `openjdk-7-jre-headless` and `openjdk-7-jre`.

When I type `java` in the terminal in Ubuntu it suggest `openjdk-7-jre-headless` not `openjdk-7-jre`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between openjdk-6-jre, openjdk-6-jre-headless, openjdk-6-jre-lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280872/difference-between-openjdk-6-jre-openjdk-6-jre-headless-openjdk-6-jre-lib)

Answer (score 22):

The difference between the two can quickly be summed up as the following

- The `openjdk-7-jre-headless` package is used when you don't need to draw anything in the graphical user interface. For example a background service or a terminal application. It's commonly used on servers.
- The `openjdk-7-jre` package includes the `openjdk-7-jre-headless` package since it contains most of the Java features. It is commonly found on on desktops.
- The `openjdk-7-jre` package isn't recommended to install on a server since it installs extra software that is not commonly used on a server.

Comment: thanks pal, what about `openjdk-11-jdk-headless` and `openjdk-11-jdk` on Linux(Ubuntu 18.10)?.

Comment: @christianbueno.1 same thing but jdk includes developer tools in addition to the runtime environment