# Docker build fails with Hash Sum Mismatch error

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am trying to create a simple docker image.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install wget
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
```

During default-jre install, it always fails with below error.

[image]

[image]

I also did `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` - does not help.

How can i fix this?

Comment: any comment before downvoting would be helpful!!

Comment: @VonC, Ok, I will be careful next time

Comment: To moderators: docker questions are Stack Overflow questions and have *nothing* to do with Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented on [this issue](https://github.com/rednut/docker-unifi-video-controller/issues/2#issuecomment-210988286), try with [`default-jre-headless`](https://github.com/pataquets/docker-default-jre-headless/blob/master/Dockerfile) instead:

```
RUN apt-get install -q -y default-jre-headless
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Whats wrong with deafult-jre? I have used in the past which worked just fine.

Comment: @KitKarson not sure, but considering a jre-headless usually refers to servers that are not connected to a monitor and don't have X11 installed, that seems a better fit for a docker environment whose base image doesn't have X11 either. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/24280872/6309