# How to run a java GUI on mac osx after ssh

Tags: java, macos, ssh, terminal

I am using java 1.7.0_67 on mac osx 10.7.5. Here is my hello world gui:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class helloWorld extends JFrame {
    helloWorld(String title) { 
        this.setSize(500,500); 
        setTitle(title); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       helloWorld window = new helloWorld("Helloworld");
       window.setVisible(true);
       window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }
}
```

This runs just fine when i open a mac terminal and type `java helloWorld`. However, when I ssh into my mac from another host, set my `DISPLAY` env variable, and run, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkedHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
    at helloWorld.<init>(helloWorld.java:8)
    at helloWorld.main(helloWorld.java:14)
```

This used to work on Java 1.6, from what I've been able to research this appears to be a purposeful break.

Any ideas how I can get my gui to display after ssh-ing in from a remote host? I don't want to use X11 (would prefer native gui rendering).

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. `-Djava.awt.headless=false` also doesn't work for me. from what I understand, this is a mac-specific problem because of how mac osx sets up a terminal started through Terminal vs started through ssh. `ssh -X` doesn't work either

Comment: use `ssh -X` to enforce X11 protocol tunneling under ssh.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No X11 DISPLAY variable" - what does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: Thanks - I had seen that one, but that's about displaying on a linux box, not on mac os x - for that matter I don't even know why the error mentions X11 since I'm not using X11 and displaying the gui natively

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès unfortunately this does not work - here i'm using mac os directly to display the gui, not X11

Comment: Then you should install X11 for your mac, no way! http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès i do have X11 already on my mac, but prefer the mac's native rendering (esp wrt fonts). thanks though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java developers [chose to use the headless Toolkit](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2013-May/005751.html) when running in an ssh session on Mac OS X. You can convince Java to go ahead and display the GUI anyway by setting the `AWT_TOOLKIT` environment variable to `CToolkit`. For example, in bash:

```
export AWT_TOOLKIT=CToolkit
java helloWorld
```

With the variable set, your GUI should display as you expect.

Comment: @duskwuff - this worked for me, curious as to what you think about this solution

Comment: This even works when I have multiple users logged in to one mac with multiple desktops: seems it chooses by user-id, which makes sense.

Comment: Though curiously, it doesn't work on my MBP - just on the Mac Minis we have as build agents. Perhaps it's because I have (had) a Quartz session locally? I can trivially 'open /Applications/Sikuli.app' and see an icon on the dock, so the login sessions are somehow communicating.

Comment: Java 1.8.0_45 on MBP and 1.7.0_71 on mac minis could also be a factor.

Comment: Yup - Copied 1.7 to my MBP and set JAVA_HOME to it. Combined with AWT_TOOLKIT, it happily started up from ssh on the Mac desktop.

Comment: this did not work for me on ubuntu - however I was running intellij idea fine with X11 forwarding, but when I started my own app in the intellij IDE, then I got following error: 

Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get `WindowServer is not available` followed by a stack trace that mentions `LWCToolkit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. To connect to the window server on Mac OS X, the process must be in the current user's [login session](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/Concepts/SystemContexts.html). SSH is not part of the login session, so processes run through SSH cannot connect to the window server, and thus cannot display a GUI.

Comment: really? i can do this on mac osx 10.7.3 and Java 1.6.0_29, did something change between versions? in any case, any way I can fake this (e.g. set environment variables, change some config file etc)?

Comment: I don't know why this might have worked on previous versions of Mac OS X. And no, there is no way to override this behavior.

Comment: I can 'open some.jpg' in an ssh shell and it will appear on my desktop, and 'open some.sh' will execute 'some.sh ; exit' in a terminal window with all the desktop env-vars defined, and if I use the -W option it will wait for the application to quit (though annoyingly it won't pass in arguments after --args), so this answer isn't strictly true. (Though I'm running as admin)