# Why this code don't work on CodeEval?

Tags: java

So, code below, that takes serial numbers as arguments from txt file, works correctly on my computer.  Every number is written on one line. So, here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static int fiboComputingAct(int serial){
        if (serial == 1 || serial == 2) {
            return 1;
        }else{
            int nMinus2 = 1;
            int nMinus1 = 1;
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 3; i <= serial; i++){
                result = nMinus1 + nMinus2;
                nMinus2 = nMinus1;
                nMinus1 = result;   
            }
            return result;
        }   
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        try {
            File textFile = new File("texts/1.txt"); //"texts/1.txt" will be replaced on args[0] in codeeval
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(textFile);
            int fiboSerialNumber;
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                fiboSerialNumber = scan.nextInt();
              System.out.println(fiboComputingAct(fiboSerialNumber));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File is not found");}   
        }   
    }
```

But it doesn't work in CodeEval. That's what the site compiler say:

> Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file Exception in thread
>   "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:  No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
>   but this program performed an operation which requires it.    at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
>     at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:535)  at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)     at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385)     at
>   javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.(SwingUtilities.java:1759)
>     at
>   javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1834)
>     at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1697)  at
>   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:863)    at
>   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:667)   at
>   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:638)   at
>   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:609)   at
>   Main.main(Main.java:45)

Comment: did you mean args[0] ?

Comment: So it looks like CodeEval doesn't give you a GUI to put your error messages on.  Instead of popping up a `JOptionPane` when you get an exception, just `e.printStackTrace()` instead.

Comment: @azurefrog: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stack trace, the error is occurring here:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File is not found");
```

Taking a look at the documentation for the [`HeadlessException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html), we see that it is:

> Thrown when code that is dependent on a keyboard, display, or mouse is called in an environment that does not support a keyboard, display, or mouse.

A bit more [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean) makes me believe that CodeEval is probably trying to execute your code in a headless linux environment.

To avoid this error, just replace the graphical error reporting with a simple `e.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` block.