# Java - appletviewer in Command Prompt

Tags: java, applet

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:437)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:384)
        at sun.applet.AppletViewer.<init>(AppletViewer.java:159)
        at sun.applet.StdAppletViewerFactory.createAppletViewer(AppletViewer.java:100)
        at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1140)
        at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1074)
        at sun.applet.Main.run(Main.java:156)
        at sun.applet.Main.main(Main.java:98)
```

I am getting the above error on compiling the file - "`HelloWorldApplet.html`" in command prompt with the command -

```
appletviewer HelloWorldApplet.html
```

Comment: Have you already checked the `No X11 DISPLAY variable was set` from the exception message?

Answer (score 1):

Your command

```
appletviewer HelloWorldApplet.html
```

Actually launches the user interface tool Applet Viewer that launches your applet and displays it in a standalone application. You are running the code on a Linux based operating system which uses X11 or X.org as the user-interface service (server).

In order to allow you application to connect to this user-interface service the connection parameters must be present in a shell variable `DISPLAY`. If you are working on the machine you are trying to execute this command at. Try to execute the following before launching `appletviewer`.

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

This instructs to set the shell variable `DISPLAY` to the first connected local display.

Related or duplicate to: ["No X11 DISPLAY variable" - what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean)