# java.awt.HeadlessException - No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it

Tags: java, ldap

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 machine installed with java8 version. I've installed 389 Ldap server, but when I am trying to execute command `389-console`, iam getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at com.netscape.management.client.console.Console.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.netscape.management.client.console.Console.main(Unknown Source)
```

I even ran command `DISPLAY=:0.0`, but still getting above error only while executing `389-console`

Please tell me how to fix above?

Comment: Did you _export_ the `DISPLAY` variable?  Is X running on your system?  Are you logged in to a graphical console or via SSH?  If via SSH do you have X port forwarding on?

Comment: @JimGarrison  iam using ssh, how to check X port forwarding on?

Comment: Try using the `-Y` option when setting up the SSH connection.  This will work only if the local system is running XWindows.  If the local system is Windows you must have an XServer installed and configured (i.e. Cygwin-X or some other XServer)

Comment: @JimGarrison My local machine is ubuntu 14.04 and iam doing ssh into another ubuntu mahcine ( which is 12.04 ). Could you please tell what should I do?

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 1):

maybe its already late but the question was still not answered so i will answer it for anyone who follows this link.

When logging into the server try using the `-X` flag

`ssh -X username@hostname`

Hope it helps