# No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires error when launching jmeter on Centos

Tags: server, jmeter, performance-testing, centos7, jmeter-plugins

I have installed jmeter on a server but when i try to launch jmeter i get the following error error

```
 No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it
```

Jmeter installed on CentOS along with java.

I tried export DISPLAY=:0 and this export DISPLAY=:0.0 but no luck

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean?

Answer (score 0):

run SSH command with "-X" param (without commas)
sample:

```
ssh user@server -X <enter>
```