# No X11 Display variable was set, installing netbeans from command line using MobaXTerm

Tags: netbeans, installation, sh, suse, x11-forwarding

I am trying to install netbeans from the command line using mobaxterm on suse enterprise. I have set X11 Forwarding when creating the session. However, I still get the following error when I try to run the downloaded netbeans script:

```
    No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

    Exception: java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean) solution, but it didn't cut it.

UPDATE

I was able to resolve this by manually changing sshd_config:

Under

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Make sure you have the following set:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you connect?

Try `echo $DISPLAY` after `ssh -X susehost`. Depending from where you connect to `susehost`, X11 forwarding may not work.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, see my edited question above.