# Minecraft Forge on Raspberry pi

Tags: linux-kernel, x11, minecraft, raspberry-pi4

I trie to install a 1.12.2 minecraft forge server on a Raspberry 4. But I get this error:

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:548)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
        at net.minecraftforge.installer.InstallerPanel.run(InstallerPanel.java:408)
        at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.launchGui(SimpleInstaller.java:170)
        at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.main(SimpleInstaller.java:143)
```

Im Iin via putty and enablet the x11 forwarding. I use Xming in the background.

What means the error? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No X11 DISPLAY variable" - what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: Try using nogui parameter