# Error:No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it

Tags: java, x11

I am using ssh from my mac machine and running FlexFlux for Flux Balance Analysis(FBA). Then I got this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:  No X11 DISPLAY
> variable was set, but this program performed an operation which
> requires it.  at
> java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
> at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)  at
> java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)     at
> javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:233)    at
> flexflux.analyses.result.FBAResult.plot(FBAResult.java:260)   at
> flexflux.applications.FlexfluxFBA.main(FlexfluxFBA.java:157)

Answer (score 0):

I got inspired by

> If you've connected from another machine via SSH, you use the -X
> option to display the graphical interface on the machine you're
> sitting at (provided there's an X server running there (such as xming
> for windows, and your standard Linux X server)
> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean)

I realized that I need to install an X server for Mac.

So I installed XQuartz on my Mac by following instructions from the Mac OS X section of [How do I run graphical programs remotely from a Linux server?](https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=280461906)

Then ssh from XQuartz instead of my default terminal. Now it works!