# How do I enable X11 display on Ubuntu 20.04? (I have it installed locally)

Tags: x11

Any time I'd like to run a file that opens a window, I get the following error:

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.(Window.java:548)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:423)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:388)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:180)
at hw04.GameOfLife.(GameOfLife.java:23)
at hw04.GameOfLife.main(GameOfLife.java:147)

EDIT: I ran sudo apt-get install libx11-dev and it says I already have it installed... I don't know where to go from here

Comment: setenv DISPLAY=":0.0" - is the X server actually running?

Comment: Nothing happens when I enter DISPLAY=":0.0" into terminal

Comment: If literally nothing happens then you haven't given us the whole story. The message should go from "No X11 DISPLAY was set" to something like "Could not open Display". Are you trying to start the program from the same shell you just set the DISPLAY in ? Is X11 running ?

Comment: I tried running my program. I get that error message above, I ran DISPLAY=":0.0" Then, when trying to run my program again, I get the same error (I ran it in the same shell)

Comment: Does any of this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean