# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException

Tags: ubuntu, fastq

I am running a program FASTQC in the command line(Ubuntu terminal on windows 10 PC) but got the error of the following. I am not sure how to solve this and I would appreciate it if some one already know the solutions.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:548)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication.<init>(FastQCApplication.java:63)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication.main(FastQCApplication.java:338)
```

Best,
Amare

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the command line that you are using and the version of the program.

Comment: fastqc  -v ; it print out FastQC v0.11.9

Answer (score 1):

You don't say, but I suspect that you are running the program without any command line parameters. The help (`fastqc -h`) says:

> If no files to process are specified on the command line then the program
> will start as an interactive graphical application.  If files are provided
> on the command line then the program will run with no user interaction
> required.  In this mode it is suitable for inclusion into a standardised
> analysis pipeline.

If you want to run it in non-interactive mode (which is how I always use it), just include the names of your FASTQ files on the command line.

Comment: thank you so much! Yes I have seen that and I was wonder to see how the interactive graphical application look like when typing fastqc on the command line.

Comment: In that case, the generic Ubuntu answer applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean